# What is $H_2$ and $H_{\infty}$ control?

Tags: noise, linear-systems, transfer-function, control-systems, system-identification

I can create a Linear Quadratic Gaussian Integral(LQGI) controller very easy by using GNU Octave. LQGI is in the area of Optimal Control Theory.

But there is something called Robust Control Theory. And every time I'm searching for that I got these in my  search field:

- $H_2$
- $H_{\infty}$

**Questions:**

1. What are they?
2. How do I apply them to control the processes?
3. Are they good for control systems?
4. Are they better that PID and LQGI?
5. Are they easy?
6. Are they for nonlinear system?
7. Can they have a Extended Kalman Filter?
8. What's the difference between them both?
9. Can you show me an easy example how to apply them?
10. Other?

Comment: Hi! can you please refer each of your (many!) questions to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-infinity_methods_in_control_theory and what you don't see answered by that? It's very complicated to describe complex theory from scratch, but it's easier to discuss potential misunderstandings when one has a common "base of understanding".

Comment: Well, I don't require that I want the whole explanation. If you say that it's very complicated to describe complex theory from scratch. Then the question number 9 and 5 is answered. Thank you.

Comment: 9. was answered by the simple example in the wikipedia article. That's why I'm asking you to make clear what you couldn't answer in your own research! We can't hammer the knowledge into your brain, so it's up to you to more closely define what you need helpf with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They are system norms, a metric that you can compare two different systems in terms of their generalized gain and spread. You can look these up no need for attaching physical motivation.
2. You don't. They are for assesing and using in the optimization programs.
3. Yes, but only if you know what you are doing.
4. Can be. But again, they are for assessment and optimization. If you hit the minimum with a PID controller then it won't make any difference. But hitting the minimum is pretty much unlikely.
5. Unfortunately no.
6. see 5 (you can pull some tricks by bounding the nonlinearity with a linear system etc. or for very limited nonlinear operators you can apply them)
7. Not applicable. They are different things.
8. They are different norms. But both of them are norms. Read about them.
9. See the documentation of `hinfsyn` of matlab
10. Yes

Comment: Thank you for the answers. They are just methods to find the robust control law $L$ ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No they are most of the cases used for coming up with a dynamic controller $K(s)$

Comment: And $K(s)$ is a matrix of transfer functions?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Yes, or a state space system.

Comment: Where is H_2 and H-inf most applied? Space? Industry? Cars?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No such statistics is available. Don't believe what people claim. PID is the king the rest is scattered everywhere

Comment: PID is the king? No. PID is only for SISO systems and has no observer/kalman filter. Everyone know that LQG is the best  ; - )

Comment: Quite inaccurate.

Comment: Why? The reason people using PID is because they don't know LQG or other controllers. I haven't seen PID for MIMO systems

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That's still very very inaccurate. People are not stupid. The industry is running 95+% PID controllers. Just ask yourself can all be really ignorant on LQ theory which is roughly 50 years old. Also it shows that you haven't read the most famous paper on LQG. Search for **Guaranteed Margins for LQG Regulators**, by John Doyle and read the abstract.

Comment: PID is over 100 years old and LQG have robustness, but no guaranteed margins for stability. That means it can have stability margins. But it's not guaranteed if you don't do some analysis. PID have a very high sensitivity for fequency due to the D-part. Most of the times PI controllers are used. People are steering bilnd att John C Dolye's article when it comes to LQG controller. LQG is robust for the industry, but can be unrobust when it comes to sending a satelite to Jupiter. The reason PID are used is because people with low education need to be able to handle it.

Comment: Starting from the robustness issue to Gaussian assumptions in the industrial processes that is certainly not true. You are asking H2 norm and claiming that LQG is the best. Had you had the full picture, you would be dealing with H2 norms all over the place because LQG is the special case of H2 norm control. That gives away your education level about LQG theory. Also these are model based solution that's why nobody bothers with them. Go to any industry and try to convince to model something accurately manage to make it work then we talk again. Nobody will give state space matrices to you

Comment: I just want to have others opinions about H2 and H inf. MPC is used in the industry and that's model based too. LQG with EKF fits nonlinear systems.

Comment: So which one do you prefer? H2 or Hinf?

Comment: I have now read aboot H infinity and you are totally right. H inf controller is totally robust and better that LQG. I found that H infinity control was quite easy. H infinity have also an observer too. Robust observer.